# sed: replacing text between two strings, without editing whole line

Tags: bash, encryption, sed, passwords, shadow

I am trying to make a Raspberry Pi configurator script (before booting the pi for the first time) and I want implement a feature to set a password. I found out that the password can be set under /etc/shadow but it needs to be encrypted.

Long story short:

How do I replace just the hash between the two strings **pi:** and the second **:** with sed?

```
pi:$6$FVPr/I.sQGI3ab3z$rmQMzZDghl/.sJyohBZ2B4Z4Bxkr.zOZJ5c4pVJlHTZEGbO28CoXhgPUZ/gds5km3puT9O2b.K0bIjbNeNTSW/:18277:0:99999:7:::
```

The output I want with my script:

e.g.

```
pi:$6$salty-boi$nt6OkKwSfV4kkk2mcEjEZW1z9rChDK9VeE.c7LE5oFv4Zd.KQbqlN2mSnc9EbcAB.iIlvhRCT10Y6ovLWvaLu.:18277:0:99999:7:::
```

I tried this:

```
sed -i "s|pi:.*:|pi:$RPI_PASSWD_ENCRYPTED:|g" shadow
```

But the output I get is this:

```
pi:$6$saltypi$NpLE895oMWEr3R6p9f1dZnekSeJq8QdAk8tQu08rTF3gsnKVoKX7Z.JsNyBCg.o/QamYgzr.w7dVoRyi5nFBM.:
```

Without this afterwards: `18277:0:99999:7:::`

Here's an example of my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
exitstatus=$?
RPI_PASSWD=$(whiptail --inputbox "Type a password for user pi. Press cancel to skip." 8 40 --title "Changing default password" --ok-button "Ok" --cancel-button "Cancel" 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)
if [ $exitstatus = 0 ]; then
   RPI_PASSWD_ENCRYPTED=$(openssl passwd -6 -salt saltypi $RPI_PASSWD)
   sed -i "s|pi:.*:|pi:$RPI_PASSWD_ENCRYPTED:|g" shadow
fi
exit 1
```

[Here's the full code.](https://github.com/ungeskriptet/Raspberry-Pi-Configurator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sed's `*` operator is greedy and will eat up to the last `:` at the end of the line.

You could use a not-colon bracket expression followed by `*`, which will only match up to the next `:`,

```
"s|pi:[^:]*:|pi:$RPI_PASSWD_ENCRYPTED:|g"
```